# Prove there isn't a continuous surjection $f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ (without compactness)

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Definitions:

> Continuous: A map $f: X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, is continuous if the preimage in $X$ of any open set in $Y$ is open.
>
> Subspace topology: If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, the subspace topology on a set $S \subset X$ is $\mathcal{T}_S = \{S \cap U : U \in \mathcal{T}\}$.

The problem says that $[0, 1]$ is a topological space with the subspace topology, meaning some sets that I would not think is open, like $[0, 1]$, is an open set, so this kind of threw me off. I know from a different class that continuity preserves compactness, so I already know that there doesn't exist a continuous function, but we're not allowed to use compactness for this problem.

Is there a way to show using the subspace topology of $[0, 1]$ that there isn't a continuous surjection from the topological space $[0, 1]$ with the subspace topology onto $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Hint: The image of a connected subset is connected. Now what happens to the image of $[0,1)$?

Comment: Well, this is a compactness property. You can avoid using the word *compact*, but that is the idea you are using.

Comment: You may not even use that a continuous function on $[a,b]$ assumes its maximum?

Comment: I would have to prove things like the image of a connected subset is connected and that a continuous function on a closed set assumes its maximum, but I am only allowed to prove them using things we covered in class (which might be tedious to tell you the details of everything we covered the entire semester)

Comment: Think of it this way then: Let $x$ be the image of $1$ and split the complement of $\{x\}$ into two disjoint open sets in the obvious way. The preimages of these sets are now disjoint and open.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The preimages of disjoint sets need not be disjoint

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, they do (but this is still only a hint, as the preimages might be missing other points that $1$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft The preimage the two disjoint open sets is $[0, 1)$ which is still connected

Comment: It might not be all of $[0,1)$ since other elements might be sent to $x$ also.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft But it could be all of $[0, 1)$ so that doesn't prove anything, does it?

Comment: Well, if it is $[0,1)$ then that set could be written as a disjoint union of non-empty open sets, which is not possible.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So does this mean that there is a continuous surjection?

Comment: No, as the argument by Hagen von Eitzen in his answer shows. It just gets slightly tricky to translate into things you have already seen

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is it true that every connected proper subset of $[0, 1]$ maps to a non-connected subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: No, why would they?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So in order to show that a function is not continuous, we have to show a connected set in the domain that maps to a non-connected set in the codomain. Since we can't show such an example, does that mean we have to use a different approach besides connectedness?

Answer (score 1):

Let's cheat and only use that $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded:

For each $k\in\mathbb N$ pick $x_k\in[0,1]$ with $f(x_k)=k$.
Starting with $I_0=[0,1]$, which contains all $x_k$,  we can repeatedly split $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ into two subintervals $[a_n,\frac{a_n+b_n}2]$, $[\frac{a_n+b_n}2,b]$ and one of these contains infinitely many $x_k$ and we let $I_{n+1}$ be that interval.
Then the intersection $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} I_n$ is a singleton set $\{a\}$, where $a\in[0,1]$. A suitable subsequence $x_{k_n}$ of the $x_k$ converges to $a$, henc by continuity $f(x_{k_n})\to f(a)$, which is absurd.

Comment: We don't have bounded in our class since we don't have metric spaces yet

Comment: @eyes: I would be surprised if you don't have "bounded" on the real line. A bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ simply means a subset contained in $[-a,+a]$ for some real number $a>0$.